NextWindow driver Touchscreen problems HP All in One
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on HP TouchSmart 7320 PC. It is an all-in-one computer. It has a touchscreen.
The touchscreen does not work under Ubuntu 24.04.1.
Under Windows 7 & 8 it needs the NextWindow driver to work https://support.lenovo.com/be/en/downloads/ds020787
Since Windows 10 & 11, Windows downloads the touchscreen driver itself.
For Ubuntu I tried the following methods:
https://github.com/glorang/nwfermi
Result: after several attempts, one touchpoint started working partially, but still with errors
Does anyone have a proven method for correct touchscreen operation under Ubuntu 24.04.01?
